# vue this. $ parent If called, does it return itself?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

[image]

[image]

My guess is that there is no App component parent, which is the root component.
I think undefined should be normal. Am I thinking wrong?

So if you look at the code, you'll see getting $ undefined by $ parent. $ Parent.

Comment: What is you real issue with this mater of fact ?

Comment: If you call this. $ Parent on the root component,
I expected undefined,

I am wondering what the Vue instance is all about.

Comment: Why do you need undefined?

Comment: I was studying with a vue study book.

In the book, I was told that if there was no parent, undefined would come out, but I was wondering why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Vue.js [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/instance/state.js) you'll see this line in the `initProps` function ..

```
const isRoot = !vm.$parent
```

Which means that the absence of a `$parent` does signify that this is the root Vue instance. So it's normal that you're getting undefined in this case.

Comment: If you call this. $ Parent on the root component,
Should not the undefined value come?

Comment: Oh, I understand.

The root component has no parent, so the root component itself is returning.